# How can I use STIX2 to write other language documents?

Tags: fonts, stix2, vietnamese

I'm trying to use `stix2` font to write document in Vietnamese, but I have a hard time figuring out why it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top = 3.5cm, right = 2.5cm, left = 2.5cm, bottom = 3.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} % Bold math characters  
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Awesome symbol
% \usepackage{background}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip     {15pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip     {15pt}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{15pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{15pt}
}
\makeatother

% Increase spaces between equations
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}


\begin{document}

Đây là một dòng chữ tiếng Việt 

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \nu\Delta u &= f &\quad& \text{in } \Omega\times (0, T],  \\ 
    u(x, 0) &= u_0(x) && \text{in } \Omega, \\
    u &= 0 && \text{on } \partial\Omega\times [0, T]. 
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```

This is the result if I use `\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}`. As you can see, the math equations is correctly showing `stix2` font, but not the texts since it's in Latex default font.

[image]

And here is the result if I use `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`. This time it does show the correct font, but it misses a few characters. Moreover, it gives some errors as followed.

```
Command \ocircumflex unavailable in encoding T1.
Command \uhorn unavailable in encoding T1.
Command \ecircumflex unavailable in encoding T1.
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Subsequent OP's question shows OP switching to an alternative font. (`stix2` LaTeX package doesn't support T5 encoding anyway.) Consider this one solved? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686660/250119