# Using STIX2 with Times number font

Tags: times, stix2, timesfont

How can I use `stix2` to type math equations while all number whether it's in mathmode or textmode still print out as Times font as in textmode. (In the code below I have to use Times New Roman font for text since `stix2` doesn't support Vietnamese characters)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top = 3.5cm, right = 2.5cm, left = 2.5cm, bottom = 3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{stix2} % Use this instead of mtpro2 since it's free
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % set Times as the default text font
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} % Bold math characters  
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Awesome symbol

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \text{Textmode number:}&\quad 0123456789 \\ 
  \text{Mathmode number:}&\quad 0123456789
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \text{Textmode number:}&\quad u(x,\text{0}) = u_{\text{0}}(x) \\ 
  \text{Mathmode number:}&\quad u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: using pdftex it really is not feasible to change fonts for text digits automatically. If you want text and math to use the same digits specify times digits for math (which is easy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to use the text font digits in math rather than conversely.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top = 3.5cm, right = 2.5cm, left = 2.5cm, bottom = 3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}

\usepackage{stix2} % Use this instead of mtpro2 since it's free
\usepackage{tgtermes}

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{`9}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} % Bold math characters  
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Awesome symbol

\begin{document}

Trong toán học, các số tự nhiên được sử dụng để đếm (như trong ``có sáu đồng 
xu trên bàn'') và thứ tự (như trong ``đây là thành phố lớn thứ ba trong cả nước''). 
Đôi khi, các số tự nhiên có thể xuất hiện dưới dạng một bộ mã thuận tiện 
(nhãn hoặc ``tên''), nghĩa là, như những gì các nhà ngôn ngữ học gọi là số danh 
nghĩa, loại bỏ nhiều hoặc tất cả các thuộc tính của một số theo nghĩa toán học. 
Tập hợp các số tự nhiên thường được kí hiệu bằng kí hiệu 
$\mathbb{N}$.
\begin{align*}
  \text{Textmode number:}&\quad \text{0123456789} \\ 
  \text{Mathmode number:}&\quad 0123456789
\end{align*}
Trong tiêu chuẩn của ISO 80000-2 và tài liệu giáo khoa chuẩn của Việt Nam, 
số tự nhiên được định nghĩa là các số nguyên không âm $0, 1, 2, 3,\dotsc$ 
(đôi khi được ký hiệu chung là biểu tượng $\mathbb{N}_{0}$, để nhấn mạnh rằng 
số $0$ cũng được bao gồm), trong khi những số khác bắt đầu bằng $1$, tương ứng 
với các số nguyên dương $1, 2, 3,\dotsc$ (đôi khi được ký hiệu chung bằng ký hiệu 
$\mathbb{N}_{1}$, $\mathbb{N}^{+}$, hoặc $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ với nhấn mạnh rằng 
số $0$ bị loại trừ).
\begin{align*}
  \text{Textmode number:}&\quad u(x,\text{0}) = u_{\text{0}}(x) \\ 
  \text{Mathmode number:}&\quad u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)
\end{align*}

(Text from \texttt{https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Số\_tự\_nhiên})

\end{document}
```

[image]

I replaced `ptm` with TeX Gyre Termes. The same with `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` would give

[image]

Comment: It works! But it gives a warning `Font shape 'T5/qtm/m/sl' in size <12> not available
(Font) Font shape 'T5/qtm/m/it' tried instead.`. Should I ignore it?

Comment: @Bakkune &es, it’s innocuous, unless you really need slanted shape.